# update data based on primary key vs indexed key in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need community help to get depth knowledge on this...Thanks in advance.

- Suppose I have a table users with customers details with 20 columns.
- Primary key is cust_id (int) and other cust_type (int) field is an
  indexed field.
- This table contains 2500000 rows.
- cust_type=2 contains 150 records.

Now which approach will be better performance wise-

- Update 150 records based on cust_type field like

  update users set
     is_deleted=1 where cust_type=2;
- First get 150 primary keys by select statement like

  select cust_id
     from useres where cust_type=2

  and then update these primary keys like

  update users set is_deleted=1 where cust_id in (1,2,3,4....,150);
- First get 150 primary keys by select statement like

  select cust_id
     from useres where cust_type=2

  and then update these primary keys one by one like `update users set is_deleted=1 where cust_id=1` then 2 and so on.

Comment: As you said `cust_type (int) field is an indexed field` the best approach would be step one `update users set is_deleted=1 where cust_type=2;`

Comment: plz consider it is executing on production server with high traffic and this is a basic table which will use almost all queries along with joins with other tables also....suppose no. of rows increase by this condition for an example 500 rows and this update took 1 second or more time then it can lock other queries also....please elaborate little bit about internal mysql methodology, by which we can avoid locking etc..

Comment: Thats a pretty big topic even for an answer to provide. The idea is its always better to run less queries in production server since each query will require resource and network usage. So while you do update on a pretty big table on an index key it would be pretty fast and considering the locking issue, it will be insignificant. From my experience we have master slave replication and some table has more than `10 M` records and update with index value in the where clause never had any issue. check here  http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/24/improving-the-performance-of-large-tables-in-mysql.html

Comment: Thanks Abhik, what about update based on multiple conditions in where clause...